# Force when an object exerts to the floor when released from different heights

Tags: forces, momentum

Based on my understanding, if I release an object from a height, there will be only the force mg exerted on the floor. But, why the damage an object makes to the floor is different when it is released from different heights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the answer of user1364427, the momentum p is decisive for the impact on the ground. The momentum depends on the mass m (can be assumed to be approximately constant here) and the velocity v. The formula for the impulse is

```
p = m * v [equation 1].
```

In turn, the speed depends on the hight, because from then on, the mass accelerates due to the gravitational force g (or acceleration a).
For uniformly accelerated motions, as here (in physics called as a free fall with / without air resistance), for the acceleration

```
a -> a = F / m = G / m = g. [equation 2]
```

Looking now at the fall height s, it is calculated according to

```
s (t) = 1/2 * g * t^2 

t = sqrt(2 * s/g) [equation 3].
```

For the case velocity, we get by using equation 2 for "gravity from the earth"

```
v (t) = a * t = g * t [equation 4]
```

Substituting equation 3 into equation 4 (transformed into t) yields:

```
v = g * sqrt(2 * s/g)

v = sqrt(2 * s * g^2/g)

v = sqrt(2 * s * g) [equation 5]
```

Let's just put equation 5 in equation 1:

```
p = m * sqrt(2 * s * g)
```

and one can see that **the momentum depends on the fall height s** and on the gravity g and the mass m as well.

---

Another approach is to use the potential energy E_pot at the hight s and to tranform this to kinetic energy E_kin.

```
E_pot = m * g * s [equation A]

E_kin = 1/2 * m * v^2 [equation B]
```

Now we assume that all potential energy transforms to kinetic energy we get:

```
E_pot = E_kin

m * g * s = 1/2 * m * v^2

g * s = 1/2 * v^2
```

Rearring this to v leads to

```
v^2 = 2 * g * s

v = sqrt(2 * g * s) [same equation as [equation 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The force is not mg but rather an impulse exerted by the floor in order to change the momentum mv of the object, either reverse it if the body is elastic or stop it entirely if it is plastic. Therefore it depends on the height.